# javascript:OpenPopUpPage will close automatically on safari web browser

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, css

I have the following code to display a pop-up window:-

```
<li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on">
    <a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://192.168.8.221/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera One</a>
</li>
<li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on">
    <a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://192.168.8.95/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=736',1200,1200);" unselectable="on">Camera Two</a>
</li>
```

The problem I am facing is regarding safari web browser, which will automatically close the pop-up menu and will do a full refresh after a while. On the other hand I tested this on other web browsers such as IE, FireFox, Chrome, there is no problem and the pop-up will stay opened? And idea about this problem on Safari 5.1.7? . I think the problem is related to the fact that safari will do a full refresh after  specific period of time, and when it refreshes the web page the pop-up will disappear.

**::EDIT::**

i found the cause of the problem. i have defined an "Enable asynchronous Automatic refresh" for my Announcement web App, and when the Announcment is auto refreshed it will close the opened dialog pop-up. while on chrome, IE, Firefox the dialog will stay opened during the automatic refresh ...
So for now i disable the automatic refresh , till i can understand how to force Safari, to react as the other web browsers...

Comment: Your edit should be added as an answer

Comment: i do not think it is the exact right solution, to disable automatic refersh. as i need to keep automatic refresh enabled on production, and at the same time I need to find a way to force Safari not to close any opened pop-up during the automatic refersh , same as IE , firefox and chrome do ...